# какие функции вызываются при выполнении операций в postgres

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, отладка, llvm

Необходимо реализовать прозрачное шифрование в postgre. Для этого понадобилось найти, какие функции вызываются при срабатывании INSERT и SELECT. Использовал LLVM-LLDB на SELECT:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать то же самое с INSERT - не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
процесс базы стопится и не даёт сделать вставку. Всё делал про одному мануалу https://eax.me/lldb/.
Что может быть не так? как узнать, какие функции вызываются при вставке (в случае SELECT это secure_read и тд)? И, если кто знает, как изменить код функций в исходниках?

Comment: `в случае SELECT это secure_read` - нет. Абсолютно. Ну и смотреть трассировку от psql (!).... Ну разве только вы о шифровании соединения между клиентом и базой (т.е. о SSL) спрашиваете.

Comment: я запускал базу от пользователя postgres, написав psql. Потом смотрел ps -a запущенные процессы, там появлялся psql. Далтше lldb -p pid l. Дальше уже SELECT и он выдал мне это. В случае с INSERT так не вышло). Как тогда мне установить, конкретно какие функции вызываются при работе с базой? Чтобы хотя бы условно на уровне «функция прочитать» расшифровывать данные, а в «функция добавить запись» зашифровывать.

Comment: Мнда. Мне жаль тратить время в пустую. Тем более здесь на ruSO, где нет аудитории по postgresql и качественный ответ, в который вложено много сил, будет просто никому не нужен (если кому ещё интересно - маякните). И, вероятно, даже автору вопроса: у вас слишком низкий уровень знаний, нужно будет слишком многое объяснять попутно. Вы ещё даже не понимаете что есть сервер, а что - клиент.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда с чего мне стоит начать?